# Passing context / authorisation with cloudfront to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is bit tricky situation I got into here,
I set up a lambda function & API gateway, then I setup cloudfront over API gateway for faster processing and achieving benefit of all the endpoint nodes provided by AWS [It should take more time using cloudfront on top of API gateway service but I am getting better result with cloudfront layer on top of it, maybe DNS resolution and AWS internal infrastructure is better]

I setup a JAVA function inside lambda which is working perfectly fine, but I want to use Context of request maker in lambda function

```
public String handleRequest(UserPOJO input, Context context) {
}
```

If I make direct lambda function request I can achieve that but it's taking too much time executing direct lambda from my Android client, also I don't find it good to expose those details, and with cloudfront I am not sure what headers should I send so that lambda detects it's cognito role and ID using `context.getIdentity().getIdentityId();` in lambda.

If someone understands my problem here and elaborate it better for other I will be glad, it is very complex to explain the problem.

Technically

1. I can make execution of lambda function directly with cognito credential provider authentication but Very slow
2. Can make API gateway request which cognito credential provider authentication, speed is better than direct lambda execution
3. Can make cloudfront request but stuck where I don't know how can I use cognito credential provider authorisation while making the request. Seemed faster than API gateway.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Cognito related information in Lambda function and you are proxying your request from API Gateway, You can use the [mapping template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) to include information you need, then you can get it from the input object.

1. I can make execution of lambda function directly with cognito credential provider authentication but Very slow.

   **I recommend you to build your Lambda function in python or javascript runtime.**
2. Can make API gateway request which cognito credential provider authentication, speed is better than direct lambda execution

   **API Gateway cannot improve the performance of your Lambda function, but API Gateway can provide API management feature for your Lambda function.**
3. Can make cloudfront request but stuck where I don't know how can I use cognito credential provider authorisation while making the request. Seemed faster than API gateway.

   **CloudFront doesn't have do anything with your Cognito credential. It just passes everything it gets to API Gateway.**

I am not sure how adding a CloudFront distribution in front of API Gateway can make the latency better except you enable the edge side cache which is not calling your Lambda function every time.

Comment: CloudFront does not pass everything. Most request headers, cookies, and the query string are stripped from the request by default, but can be added back in through cache behavior config, where appropriate. CloudFront can improve performance through connection and transport optimization without the cache enabled (that's how S3 Transfer Acceleration was implemented) ... but not for API Gateway, which is already front-ended (transparently) by CloudFront for transport purposes... so if it is helping, it might be an illusion caused by caching of responses that should not have been cached.

Comment: 3. I am not very sure how it is faster this way but I assume they have their internal DNS server and high performance network which makes hostname discovery as well data transfer faster between cloudfront to lambda journey back and forth. And cloudfront providers nearest endpoint to user.
I am still finding way out of this and let's see.